# Using clean MVP on android with RxJava: How can you keep the presenter free of any android knowledge while still observing on the UI thread?

Tags: android, rx-java, android-mvp, clean-architecture

In an effort to implement 'clean' architecture on android with the mvp pattern it is advised to treat the android framework as a plugin and not leak any android aware dependencies into the presenter layer. Using rxjava, if I have a presenter that is designed to 'push' data to the view layer I may want to have logic like this:

```
public interface SearchPresenter {

  interface ViewLayer {
  void updateResults(List<SearchResult> searchResults)
  }
  void bind(ViewLayer viewLayer);
  void unbind();
}

public class SearchPresenterImpl implements SearchPresenter {

   ViewLayer viewLayer;
   CompositeDisposable compositeDisposable;

    @Override
    public void bind(ViewLayer viewLayer) {
      this.viewLayer = viewLayer;

      compositeDisposable = new CompositeDisposable();
      compositeDisposable.add(
            searchInteractor.getSearchResults()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(this::refreshView));

}

private void refreshView(List<SearchResult> searchResults) {
    //send the results back to the view layer to update a RecyclerView      
    viewLayer.updateResults(searchResults)
}

@Override
public void unbind() {
    compositeDisposable.dispose();
}
```

However, by observing on 'AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()' this forces a dependency on:

```
import io.reactivex.android.schedulers.AndroidSchedulers
```

at which point, my presenter now knows about android and is tied to it; which I want to avoid.

What is the advised way to handle this so that the result is guaranteed to be delivered to the ViewLayer on android's UI (Main) thread while the presenter maintains no dependencies on anything android related?

Comment: Maybe the ViewLayer interface needs some method like `Observable getThread();` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()` uses Android code to schedule actions on the main thread, don't use it directly in your presenter.
instead You can refactor the presenter to take Schedulers in its constructor, in production code use the regular `AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()` and `Schedulers.io()`, in testing you can just send `Schedulers.trampoline()` or `Schedulers.immediate()` .

see this pattern in this example: https://github.com/riggaroo/GithubUsersSearchApp/blob/master/app/src/main/java/za/co/riggaroo/gus/presentation/search/UserSearchPresenter.java

and its test class here:
https://github.com/riggaroo/GithubUsersSearchApp/blob/8b83095d7a2cc8f3cb69a945224ab4c37cf54a37/app/src/test/java/za/co/riggaroo/gus/presentation/search/UserSearchPresenterTest.java

Answer (score 2):

As pointed in previous answer you can inject `Scheduler` in constructor of `Presenter` but there is at least two more possibilities.

1. You can inject `Scheduler` directly to `interactor` and then you don't need to do any manipulation in `presenter`. Then in tests you can mock your `interactor` and completely forget about `rxjava` dependency in your tests.
2. You can use `RxJavaPlugins` and `RxAndroidPlugins` to override schedulers in tests if you feel that it is fine for you to keep `AndroidSchedulers` in interactors.

So define (Kotlin):

```
object RxJavaPluginHelper {

    fun setup(scheduler: Scheduler = Schedulers.trampoline()) {
        RxAndroidPlugins.setInitMainThreadSchedulerHandler { _ -> scheduler }
        RxJavaPlugins.setComputationSchedulerHandler { scheduler }
        RxJavaPlugins.setIoSchedulerHandler { scheduler }
        RxJavaPlugins.setNewThreadSchedulerHandler { scheduler }
        RxJavaPlugins.setSingleSchedulerHandler { scheduler }
    }

    fun teardown() {
        RxAndroidPlugins.reset()
        RxJavaPlugins.reset()
    }
}
```

And then use

```
 companion object {
        @BeforeClass
        @JvmStatic
        fun setup() {
            RxJavaPluginHelper.setup()
        }

        @AfterClass
        @JvmStatic
        fun teardown() {
            RxJavaPluginHelper.teardown()
        }
    }
```

Personally I would not fight for removing this line from presenter, as whole idea behind removing `Android` imports from `Presenter` is to make it portable to different platforms, but since it is unlikely to happen I would treat it as ok.