# Mockito verify not working correctly

Tags: java, android, mockito, junit4

I am quite new to Mockito, though I have been running tests successfully before and today it just look so strange why mockito verify() method keeps telling me that a `View` method is required but not called even though I am sure `Presenter` method is calling it correctly. Here is my test code:

```
 @Test
public void loadCallPlans_shouldUpdateAdapter() {
    ArrayResponse<CallPlan> callPlans = new ArrayResponse<>();
    callPlans.data = Arrays.asList(new CallPlan[]{new CallPlan(), new CallPlan()});
    Single response = Single.just(callPlans);

    when(callPlanRepository.getCallPlans()).thenReturn(response);

    presenter.loadCallPlans("Today");

    doAnswer((Answer<Void>) invocation -> {
        Object[] args = invocation.getArguments();
        System.out.println("View.updateCallPlans() called with arguments: " + java.util.Arrays.toString(args));
        return null;
    }).when(view).updateCallPlans(anyList());

    verify(view).updateCallPlans(anyList());

}
```

I could confirm that the `updateCallPlans()` method is called because I am getting `View.updateCallPlans() called with arguments: [[]]` in the logcat. My complete log:

```
View.updateCallPlans() called with arguments: [[]]


Wanted but not invoked:
view.updateCallPlans(<any List>);
-> at    CallPlansPresenterTest.loadCallPlans_should    UpdateAdapter(CallPlansPresenterTest.java:69)
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.

Wanted but not invoked:
view.updateCallPlans(<any List>);
-> at     CallPlansPresenterTest.loadCallPlans_should    UpdateAdapter(CallPlansPresenterTest.java:69)
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.

at CallPlansPresenterTest.loadCallPlans_shouldUpdateAdapter(CallPlansPresenterTest.java:69)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethod.invoke(TestMethod.java:68)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:326)
at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie$2.run(MethodRoadie.java:89)
at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(MethodRoadie.java:97)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:310)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTestInSuper(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:131)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.access$100(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:59)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner$TestExecutorStatement.evaluate(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:147)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.evaluateStatement(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:107)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:82)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:298)
at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:87)
at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:50)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.invokeTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:218)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.runMethods(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:160)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$1.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:134)
at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:34)
at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:44)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:136)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:121)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:57)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.run(PowerMockRunner.java:59)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMainV2.main(AppMainV2.java:131)
```

If I make RxJava to return error as response, the test runs fine and `View.setError()` is correctly verified:

```
 @Test
 public void loadCallPlans_shouldShowError() {
    String error = "Error";
    Single response = Single.error(new Throwable(error));

    when(callPlanRepository.getCallPlans()).thenReturn(response);

    presenter.loadCallPlans("Today");

    doAnswer((Answer<Void>) invocation -> {
        Object[] args = invocation.getArguments();
        System.out.println("View.setError() called with arguments: " + java.util.Arrays.toString(args));
        return null;
    }).when(view).setError(anyString());

    verify(view).setError(error);

}
```

Comment: No, you don't "get `View.updateCallPlans() called with arguments: [[]]` in the logcat"; you get `View.populateItemsAdapter() called with arguments: [[]]` in the logcat.

Comment: @daniu it is a typo, it is supposed to be `View.updateCallPlans()`, I have updated the question to the right log. Thanks.

Comment: What type does `presenter.loadCallPlans` return?

Comment: @JakubCh. it returns nothing (Void)

Answer (score 0):

You are actually mocking a call to updateCallPlans

```
doAnswer((Answer<Void>) invocation -> {
        Object[] args = invocation.getArguments();
        System.out.println("View.updateCallPlans() called with arguments: " + java.util.Arrays.toString(args));
        return null;
    }).when(view).updateCallPlans(anyList());
}
```

So it will never invoke actual method.

Your verification should be inside answer invocation.

Comment: Hi Harshal, I am not mocking `updateCallPlans`, I was just stubbing a code to execute when it is invoked by mockito in order to verify that it was actually called, I still get the same result if I remove it.

Comment: Agree to your point, you are stubbing the method. and you are expecting actual invocation 1 time on updateCallPlans which is not happening. when you will replace `verify(view).updateCallPlans(anyList());` with `view.updateCallPlans(anyList());`, test will pass.

Comment: I do not seem to get you, but I need mockito to verify that the method is called which is the main reason for writing the test, `view.updateCallPlans(anyList());` is not going to do that for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just want to put it here in case someone is facing the same issue, I wasn't aware that `AndroidSchedulers` is a dirty class for mockito so I was using it directly in my presenter instead of creating a class that provides the needed schedulers via constructor. More explanation from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46570795/using-clean-mvp-on-android-with-rxjava-how-can-you-keep-the-presenter-free-of-a)